# How can I check if a user input to a float variable is a number in C++?

Tags: c++

My professor wants us to solve perimeters of shapes and with that, he wants us to put user input of the shape dimensions within a float data type. However, he wants us to terminate the program if the input is not a number e.g. "four", letters, symbols, etc.

How can I do this since isdigit() does not apply to strings and modulo isn't allowed for float data types?

Comment: Either a) read the input as a float and check if the read failed, or b) read the input as a string and then attempt to convert the string to a float. You should be able to find many questions on this site for both approaches.

Comment: _"How can I do this since isdigit() does not apply to strings"_ Strings consist of characters and you can call `isdigit` on each character.

Answer (score 2):

For schoolwork it's probably sufficient to check that the floating-point value could be extracted. For example:

```
double d = 0;
if (std::cin >> d) {
  std::cout << "Number: " << d << '\n';
} else {
  std::cerr << "Not a number! (or read error, EOF, etc.)\n";
}
```

This might be more forgiving than you want. For example, this also accepts numbers in exponential notation (e.g., "1e2" for 100), and if some enters a number followed by other caracters, e.g., "123bla", the number 123 would be parsed, leaving the "bla" in the input buffer for later.

If you need stricter validation you probably have to do the tokenization and parsing yourself. But I'm guessing that's not the point of your homework so the above is probably good enough.